# Bootstrap - fluid rows have no padding/margins when container is desktop sized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHCrs/) to show what I'm talking about.  With a `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` divs, things are pushed right up against the left side of the screen.  When I shrink the screen, the spans collapse so they're on top of each other (which is expected), *and* there's now a left margin pushing it away from that side.

Is this normal behavior?  It seems odd that they'd not implement the left margin, or intentionally set it to 0, in those cases.

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or 2? in 3 there is no more `fluid`

Comment: 2.3.2, direct from the bootstrap site (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).  Didn't know there was a 3

Comment: He is using `.span*`, so it should be 2. v3 uses `.col-**-*` instead. Note that you have that as `.contain**t**er-fluid` on the body. Fix that, and you get better performance

Comment: yeah, just go to getbootstrap.com, but yeah, in 2 `container-fluid` is not adding the margins, `.container` does

Comment: Again, you have a typo there. Its `.container-fluid`, you have `.containter.fluid` for the body of your site.

Comment: Oh, man... didn't see that, even after looking at it a lot over the last few hours.  Thanks for seeing it, and the tip about version 3

Comment: I would recommend you go with v3 (http://getbootstrap.com/). But make sure you read the [changes](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration), there are a lot of them :) Mostly improvements, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The margin on both sides on small screen is normal with Bootstrap. As for why Bootstrap decided to add the margin on small screens but not on medium screen, I don't really know why.